# How to get a mission to continue the story?

Tags: destiny

I got Destiny and I did the first mission where the guy wakes up and has to get to his ship. Now I'm stuck in the tower. There are no mission notifications or anything. How can I get the next mission and start it?

Comment: If you downvote this question, please elaborate why... I myself do not play Destiny (yet) and am not really able to help you at this point.

Comment: @Daniel Comments are completely optional. They are not required, and asking for reasons is a waste of time. If the downvotes had wanted to, they'd already have left comments.

Comment: @Frank My apologies, I shall refrain from asking for comments regarding downvotes.

Comment: @Daniel for future reference, asking for votes can generally lead to downvotes. This question is pretty easy to answer, though. Even at planetary view, you are given a visual icon for missions you can pick up and missions you can hand in. Will post answer once I can get infront of the xbox

Comment: @Timelord64 I suppose you mean "asking for comments", because I was not asking for votes. Will keep this all in mind though, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are in [the Tower](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Tower) or a similar social area that you go to between each mission (if my memory serves me correctly, it has been a while).  To get to the next mission you need to get to orbit.

I played on PS4, but according to [this screenshot](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/REMdIwmYDFY/maxresdefault.jpg) it looks like the xbox one controls are to push and hold "Y" to go to orbit.

Comment: You literally dont ever get missions from orbit. You have to talk to NPCs, in either The Tower or The Reef, not including the missions you recieve directly after the completion of the prior mission

Comment: I didn't mean to imply you get missions "while" in orbit, just that you have to go to orbit to "get to" an area that would have a mission.  But like I said, it has been a while.  Since the OP said he didn't see any mission notifications  it sounded like he may of had to go to orbit to continue anyway (and wasn't aware of how to get to orbit).  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: If OP has not left The Tower, and has only conpleted one mission, all available missions will be from the tower. Going to orbit becomes counter productive

Comment: Alright.  Perhaps I was assuming too much about his progress.  I was assuming he had nothing left to do in the tower (since there were no "mission notifications") and had no idea how to leave the tower.