# Starting a Mission

Tags: destiny

I just started playing Destiny and I'm totally at a loss. I did the tutorial at the beginning, and now I'm at the hub world. But I can't seem to figure out how to start a mission. Can somebody give me specific directions please?

Comment: @Adeese has what I believe is a correct answer, but I attempted to answer a similar question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247294/how-to-get-a-mission-to-continue-the-story/247300#247300), that may provide more information for you.

Answer (score -1):

You are now at The Tower. Have you talked to one of the NPCs there? You should have an on screen indicator telling you where to go. Once you've done that, you can go to orbit, and then open up the galaxy map (using a button in the lower left corner of the screen). From there you should have a mission indicator over Earth. Select Earth, then select the next mission to play.

Comment: just a thought, screen shots might help a bit